# Why doesn't Microsoft Edge work when downloading Exchange online powershell module

Tags: powershell, exchange, microsoft-edge

I get this error

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.18363.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    clr.dll             : 4.8.4075.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST
    dfdll.dll           : 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.18362.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///blah/Downloads/Microsoft.Online.CSE.PSModule.Client%20(1).application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Microsoft.Online.CSE.PSModule.Client.application, Version=16.0.3527.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=45baf49ae30bdb15, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\blah\Downloads\Microsoft.Online.CSE.PSModule.Client (1).application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + **Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.**
```

Comment: BTW it works fine in Internet explorer. As this is a Microsoft download from a Microsoft site using a Microsoft product its a little disappointing.

Comment: Microsoft themselves don't use Edge. I have a support ticket open with them at the moment about a Teams issue, and in their ticket update, they put "Step 8. Open a Web Browser, preferably Internet Explorer (Not Edge), and Reproduce Issue"

Comment: Check [this q/a on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9227105/1025421) for technical details.

Comment: not an answer to your question, but you could install the module Exchange Online PowerShell V2 module directly in PowerShell with `Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement`

Comment: spikey_richie, as for [Microsoft themselves don't use Edge.]. That is a blanket statement. All browsers have their issues, on specific targets, but blanket statements like this are misleading. Edge is a key offering from MS and even replaces the managed browser in Windows Intune deployments. Much work is still going into it, cross platform desktop and mobile, dual personal (work adn personcal), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a browser to do this at all?

PowerShell modules are in the MS powershelgallery.com and should be downloaded, and installed using PowerShell directly in PowerShell since that is the only place they can be used.

```
Find-Module -Name '*exchange*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
<#
# Results

Version     Name                                              Repository Description                                                             
-------     ----                                              ---------- -----------                                                             
0.4578.0    ExchangeOnlineManagement                          PSGallery  This is a public preview release of Exchange Online PowerShell V2 mod...
2.0.3.5     ExchangeOnlineShell                               PSGallery  Module for creation a session to manage Exchange Online Shell with or...
1.31.0      xExchange                                         PSGallery  Module with DSC Resources for deployment and configuration of Microso...
16.0.0.0    Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellModule PSGallery  Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellModule from the exchange o...
...
#>

Find-Module -Name 'ExchangeOnlineShell' | 
Save-Module -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" -Force
Install-Module -Name 'ExchangeOnlineShell' -Verbose
```

Install all Office 365 PowerShell Modules
https://o365reports.com/2019/11/01/install-all-office-365-powershell-modules

You can install all Office 365 PowerShell modules using a single script. You can download the script from TechNet Gallery

[Connect to all Office 365 Services PowerShell - Supports MFA too](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Script-to-4081ec0f?ranMID=43674&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-ibMqWhdwKDHnZXAddDvJ.w&epi=je6NUbpObpQ-ibMqWhdwKDHnZXAddDvJ.w&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7795_1243925&tduid=%28ir__pc6qnd03hskfth0vkk0sohzg2m2xnnk69xxexl0f00%29%287795%29%281243925%29%28je6NUbpObpQ-ibMqWhdwKDHnZXAddDvJ.w%29%28%29&irclickid=_pc6qnd03hskfth0vkk0sohzg2m2xnnk69xxexl0f00)

Using our All-in-One PowerShell script, you can connect to all Office 365 Services using a single cmdlet. It supports both MFA and non-MFA account -Exchange Online -Azure AD -SharePoint Online -Skype for Business Online -Security & Compliance Center -Teams
[Download: ConnectO365Services.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Script-to-4081ec0f/file/225256/1/ConnectO365Services.ps1)

I primarily use MS Edge and I've not had this issued when tried. Going to this URL, which is the same place PowershellGet retrieves it, works without issue.

ExchangeOnlineShell 2.0.2
Module for creating session to manage Exchange Online Shell with or without Proxy Settings. Supports MFA.
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ExchangeOnlineShell/2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, the cores of IE and microsoft edge are different, many things need to be downloaded by IE.